# jquery does not work in iexplorer

Tags: jquery, submit

The code below works perfectly in firefox and chrome, but not in iexplorer. Can anyone help me.

```
    $('form').live('submit', function()
    {

      $(this).ajaxSubmit(
      {
        target: '#target',
        url:    acao//'../paginas/addperson.php'
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery `$.live()` function currently does [not support](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) the `submit` event.

Supported events are: `click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup`

If you are not dinamically adding forms to your page, there is no need to use `live`, you could just use

```
$("form").submit(function(){
...
})
```

Or even if forms are added on-the-fly, You attach the above code to individual forms at the time of their creation